# How to set path variables in ant

Tags: ant

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH}

export PATH

SQLPATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib:${SQLPATH}

export SQLPATH
```

Hi all,

This is the path variables I am setting in my shell script. I want to set this same in my ant file. Can you please explain how to set these variables in ant?

Comment: Where do you want to use these in your build xml ?

Comment: These path variables will be used during the sql task execution

Comment: You do not need all these paths to run `sql task`